# Vue доступ к элементу по клику на него

Tags: vue.js, список, click

Есть список

```
               <b-pagination-nav
                 :click="method"
                    :limit=10
                    :value=this.currentPage
                    :hide-goto-end-buttons=true
                    :hide-ellipsis=true
                    :link-gen="linkGen"
                    :page-gen="pageGen"
                    :number-of-pages="products.lastPage"
            ></b-pagination-nav>

              methods: {
        method(e){
            console.log(e);
            console.log(this.e.target);
            console.log(this.target);
            console.log(e.target.textContent);       
             }
```

Мне по клику на li нужно получить 1, или 2, или 3, смотря, на какой элемент кликнули.

Answer (score 1):

У `vue` нет такого свойства как `method`, а есть объект `methods` - где объявляются все методы. Функция в директиве `@click` должна быть без круглых скобок. 
И зачем вы используете нативное событие при клике?

Потому правильный вариант будет :

```
methods: {
    myAvesomeClickFunction(e) {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
        //console.log(e.target.innerHtml); //или так
    }
}
```

Код в шаблоне:

```
<li @click="myAvesomeClickFunction">1</li>
<li @click="myAvesomeClickFunction">2</li>
<li @click="myAvesomeClickFunction">3</li>
```

Ссылка на песочницу https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ygtth

**UPDATE:**

Вот решение в контексте вашего вопроса
https://codesandbox.io/s/b-pagination-nav-test-c3g3g

Что бы получить текущее выбранное значение нужно для компонента `b-pagination-nav` добавить директиву `v-model` и по клику на пагинатор просто выводить ее в консоль

Comment: Без native вообще не срабатывает метод клика

Comment: @VitautHryharovich вы в песочнице пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал разные варианты, всё время ошибки. То undefined, Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: @VitautHryharovich я дал ссылку https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ygtth зайдите и посмотрите

Comment: У меня список создаётся компонентом b-pagination. Может поэтому ничего не получается

Comment: @VitautHryharovich Тогда приложите больше кода .

Comment: @VitautHryharovich вам нужно получить значение из пагинатора по которому кликнули?

Comment: Да!
Извините, пожалуйста, что немного ввёл в заблуждение и начал не с того конца свой вопрос. Просто я решал эту задачку как клик по элементу списка.

Comment: @VitautHryharovich обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужен именно текст в li

```
method: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent); //как удобнее
    console.log(e.target.html); //как удобнее
}
```

Comment: Не получилось. Ошибка Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: `e.target.textContent`

Comment: Исправлю ответ, видимо от jQuery text затеслася